# Salesforce Flow (lightning Flow) getting to a flow value programatically

Tags: visual-workflow, tracking

I'm building out an autolaunched flow.  I want to add logic to 'track' the execution - not too difficult except that I would like to log in my tracking information such as the Flow Label or API name.  Things that would help me know later what it was that actually ran.  I can get to the Flow GUID and the interview date/time but not much else appears.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this short of just typing in a text string with the flow name - not that great if the flow name changes and I forget to update the text string.

Comment: Where do you want to see this information 'tracked'? Developer console logs? Emails? Salesforce records?

Comment: Salesforce records.  I've got the basic object structure all built and the code in the Flow to create the records; however, I have wanted to capture the name of the Flow that is being executed (and version if possible) so that I could see in my tracking object what code was executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably grab what you need with the [Get Flow Metadata](https://unofficialsf.com/get-information-about-a-flow-with-getflowmetadata/) community extension.

Comment: At first blush this looks like the solution.  I installed the package but it doesn't make sense to me.  Is this intended to be used within a Lightning Flow?  What I'm looking for is a way to find out about myself while I am executing (the flow).  The only thing I know about myself is the GUID.  I can setup a call to GetFlowMetadata as an Action but it is not clear if the GUID can be passed as an identifier and secondly there are no outputs indicated on the action so how to data the results?